method OngoingStubbing.thenReturn(Optional<AddressView>) is not applicable
I have this Spring Data JPA with JUnit 5 test:
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface AddressRepository extends EntityRepository<AddressId, Address, AddressWrapper>, JpaRepository<Addresses, Long> {


@Query(value = """
                    SELECT id, name from test where :id                                                                                                          
            """, nativeQuery = true)
Optional<AddressView> get(@Param("id") String id);
}

.....

public interface AddressView {

    String getName();
    .....
}

.........

public class AddressWrapper extends SimpleEntityWrapper<Address> {

  private String street;

  @Override
  public void applyWrapper(final Address obj) {
    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(region) && (!obj.getCountry().isUs())) {
      obj.setStreet(region);
    }
  }

  public void setRegion(String street) {
    this.street= street;
  }
}

...........

public class SimpleEntityWrapper<EntityT> {

  private String id;
  private EntityT obj;

  public String getId() {
    return idString;
  }

  public void setId(final String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public EntityT getObj() {
    return obj;
  }

  public void setObj(final EntityT obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  public void applyWrapper(final EntityT obj) {
    //none
  }

}
    
......

private final AddressWrapper addressWrapper1 = new AddressWrapper();

  @Test
  public void addressRequest() {
    when(addressRepository.get(@Param("id") String id......)).thenReturn(addressWrapper1);
  }

I ger error:
Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(AddressWrapper)'

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Some of your syntax looks very strange.  Is this literally the code you've written?  What does String id...... do? I've never seen it before.  Also, where is your variable called addressMapper declared and initialised?  I think you need to show more of your code in order to be able to get an answer here.

I have updated the code

Basically the issue is how to implement method thenReturn(...) when we have Optional<Interface_view>` as a return type of a method in Spring Data JPA.

Your update doesn't help me understand. The line causing you grief is when(addressRepository.get(@Param("id") String id......)).thenReturn(addressWrapper1); but you haven't declared a variable addressRepository anywhere that I can see, and you also have that very strange expression with the six dots in a row.  I might have expected something like when(addressRepository.get(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(addressWrapper1); which would make sense, provided you had a mock variable addressRepository and had initialised the mock properly.  But I can't tell whether you've done that or not.
